# How do I find out the default server character set in mysql?

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, freebsd

Using MySQL on FreeBSD 8.2.  How do I find out the default server character set?  Is there some command I can run or file I can check?

**UPDATE**

Actually I want to know how to find both the **default** server character set *and* the **current** server character set.

Comment: Do you really mean "*server character set*"?  What are you trying to do?  See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @eggyal: 1. I want to know how. 2. If I'm creating adhoc databases (which I'll likely want in utf8) do I need to specify a character set (and collation) each time I create a database?

Comment: @eggyal I don't know how the question (even pre-edit) is an XY question. The title and body have clear statements of the problem, not the solution. To fall into the XY problem, it would have to be asking about the solution they tried rather than asking about the problem.

Comment: @SteveExdia: It was my experience from the dozens/hundreds of MySQL questions that I was answering back then that character set problems most commonly faced by MySQL questioners were to do with that of their connection rather than that of the server.  Without further detail (that OP subsequently provided in their comment above), it had the whiff of an XY question.  At least, that's my take on it now, more than 10 years later, without any particular recollection of what I specifically had in mind at the time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As documented under [Server Character Set and Collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/charset-server.html):

> Initially, the server character set and collation depend on the options that you use when you start [*`mysqld`*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysqld.html). You can use [`--character-set-server`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_character-set-server) for the character set. Along with it, you can add [`--collation-server`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_collation-server) for the collation. If you don't specify a character set, that is the same as saying [`--character-set-server=latin1`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_character-set-server).

The default server character set is therefore Windows-1252, which MySQL calls `latin1`, unless your copy of MySQL has been compiled with some other default.

The manual goes on to say:

> The current server character set and collation can be determined from the values of the [**`character_set_server`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_character_set_server) and [**`collation_server`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_collation_server) system variables. These variables can be changed at runtime.

Therefore, to discover the server character set currently in use:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set_server' ;
```

Comment: Thanks, checking the 'character_set_server' I see it is set to 'latin1'.  I would have guessed that it would be 'utf8' incorrectly.  Now I'll need to look at changing the option file under FreeBSD.

Comment: @User: See my revised answer, above.

Comment: wait! don't erase the show variable part of your answer, that was useful and actually I believe the direct answer to my question.

Comment: @User: Actually, I felt that it didn't at all answer your question about *default* server character set, from which that variable can differ if explicitly changed.  The default is always `latin1` (unless compiled otherwise).

Comment: Realizing I didn't grok your earlier comment fully.  I guess I am interested in both how to find out the _default_ server character set and the _current_ server character set.

Comment: @axelrotter: that’s a fundamental misunderstanding.  `mysqld` is the binary that the machine executes to run the MySQL server.  If you aren’t the sysadmin, you won’t be in a position to adjust those options.

Answer (score 8):

According to [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-connection.html). This is what you need:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%';
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'collation%';
```

Or even better:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'c%';
```