# Issue of server charset causes phpMyAdmin to show a notice of "Undefined offset"

Tags: mysql, configuration, phpmyadmin

After I upgraded my PHP to version 7.4.0RC4 and phpMyAdmin to version 4.9.1, there is a Notice of "Undefined offset" every time I open phpMyadmin. (see the screenshot below)

[image]

---

The line 379 in the index.php (as referred to by the Notice) is:

```php
    echo '           ' , $charsets[$charset], ' (' . $charset, ')';
```

The issue is obviously charset, and that corresponds with the missing output of "Server charset" as shown in the screenshot.

After a bit searching, I tried adding some [suggested configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16862181/1091014) into my MySQL config file (my.ini) and restart my database server, but the issue persists.

Comment: What is your serber charset? Byw, this may be a bug in phpmyadmin, in which casee you have to raise it with them.

Comment: @Shadow Not sure how I can see that. I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12327407/1091014) and tried SQL query `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set_server'`, and phpMyAdmin returned an error saying `#1146 - Table 'performance_schema.session_variables' doesn't exist`.